# Why does it return Nan when i do recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

### **Javascript**

---

i want recursion to happen. I want the sum of first 3 elements in this array. But, for some reason I am getting Nan as output. arr[n-1] returns 4 but sum(arr,n-1) is behaving unexpectedly for some reason why? i see it as sum([2,3,4,5],3-1);

```
function sum(arr, n){
      if(n>=0){
         var total = arr[n-1]+sum(arr,n-1);
         return total;
      }
    }
sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that it returns `undefined` on the last return, and attempts to use index -1 when `n == 0`. This should fix it: (1. modified >= to > 2. added an else for when it is false)

```
function sum(arr, n){
      console.log(arr, n)
      if(n>0){
         var total = arr[n-1]+sum(arr,n-1);
         return total;
      }
      else {
        return 0;
}
    }
sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 3);
```

Comment: else is unnecessary, you can direct return 0

Comment: true because of the return statement within the if, but I don't see the downside to including the else.

Answer (score 1):

In the case `n` is 0, your condition is still satisfied and you will access index `arr[-1]` which is undefined.

Mathematical operations on `undefined` produce `NaN`.